# How to save separated values from a list of numbers

Tags: python, django, function, django-rest-framework

I want to receive a list of values (numbers in this case) in a key called "sensor_data" and save those values separated but I couldn't figure out how to make this function without using another framework.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def saveData(request):
    
    values_list = []
    separated_values = values_list.split(',')
    sensor_data = {'sensor_data' : values_list }
    print (sensor_data)
    return Response()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to create list of tuples using your dictionary;

```
d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
new_d = list(d.items())

print(new_d)
```

**EDIT:**

You can define a function like below to get input from user and assign it to dictionary that you can later use;

```
def sensor_input():
    user_input = input("please provide a series of numbers (example: 1,2,3,4)")
    input_list = list(user_input.split(","))
    sensor_data ={"input_values" : input_list}
    print(sensor_data)
    return sensor_data

sensor_input()
```

Output :

```
{'input_values': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
```

Comment: the idea was that somebody put the values that he/she wants and then the program saves it separated, for example someome puts this list [1, -2, 1.5, 4, 56]

Comment: Do you want to save input as a seperate file? What you want to achieve is not clear to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, yes, i want to save the users input with a key called "sensor_data" and then save it separating all the values of the list that the user enters.